Android's WorkManager's Notification gets stuck when constraints are not met
I have a WorkManager Worker that has a required network type of NetworkType.UNMETERED as a constraint. It shows a notification while it's running.
When the device loses connection to wifi and goes to cellular, the worker goes from the RUNNING state to the ENQUEUED state (as it should), but the notification gets stuck in the status bar.
Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't the notification be dismissed if the Worker goes back to the ENQUEUED state?


I've managed to create a minimum reproducible example project for this.
This is what I have in my build.gradle.kts:
(...)
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
(...)
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")
(...)

I've added the required elements in my AndroidManifest.xml.
I'm creating the notification channel in my Application class:
private fun createDownloadsNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                NotificationChannel(
                    TEST_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Test",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW,
                )
            )
        }
    }

This is my launcher Activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("StuckNotificationDebug", "MainActivity created")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        TestWorker.enqueueTestWorker(application)// Enqueue the Worker.
    }
}

And this is my Worker:
class TestWorker(private val context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        showNotification()// The notification is shown here.

        coroutineScope {
            val job = async {
                repeat(60) { i ->// To keep the worker running, I just delay for 60 seconds.
                    delay(1_000L)
                    Log.d("StuckNotificationDebug", "after delay ($i)")
                }
            }

            job.invokeOnCompletion { exception: Throwable? ->
                when (exception) {
                    is CancellationException -> {// This gets called when the device loses wifi connection. I expected the notification to be dismissed here.
                        Log.d("StuckNotificationDebug", "CancellationException")
                    }

                    else -> {}
                }
            }

            job.await()
        }

        return Result.success()
    }

    private suspend fun showNotification() {
        val notification = createNotification()
        try {
            if (!isStopped) {
                setForeground(createForegroundInfoSafely(notification))
            }
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        }
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, TEST_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("working")
            .setOngoing(true)// I need the notification to not be dismissable by the user.
            .build()
    }

    private fun createForegroundInfoSafely(notification: Notification): ForegroundInfo {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) ForegroundInfo(
            TEST_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notification,
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_DATA_SYNC
        )
        else ForegroundInfo(TEST_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    companion object {// This object holds the constants, and the function that enqueues it.
        private const val TEST_WORKER_NAME = "TestWorkerName"
        private const val TEST_NOTIFICATION_ID = 123
        const val TEST_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "321"

        fun enqueueTestWorker(applicationContext: Context) {
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                .build()

            val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>()
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
                .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                .enqueueUniqueWork(TEST_WORKER_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest)
        }
    }
}

Note: I did not go through the trouble of programmatically asking for the permission to show notifications, so after the app is installed, I go into 'App Info' > 'Notifications', and allow it.

workmanager does not get canceled if the state changes but it already running. The constraints only prevent it from starting until the constraints are met. It is completely possible that a constraint changes so that it is not met while your worker is running

Yes, I understand that. So you're saying it is expected that the notification remains when the worker is suspended? Is there a workaround for that? I guess I'll try to call NotificationManager.notify with that notification's ID to "unbind" it from the worker/service so I can then cancel it.

The worker is not getting suspended though the started worker is still running until it completes or is timed out because it ran too long

Actually, it seems to go from the RUNNING to the ENQUEUED state. When the constraints are met again, it goes to the RUNNING state, and doWork() is executed from the beginning.
It doesn't seem right in terms of user experience to have a notification stuck there for what could possibly be days until the constraints are met again.
I'll see what I can do about this.
